# DidSelectAnnotationView method is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I am implementing ordnance survey maps. I am able to display all annotations but didSelectAnnotationView method is not calling when tap on annotation.

Here is the code, i have used below in viewForAnnotation method.

```
OSAnnotationView *view = nil;
static NSString *pinAnnotation = @"PinAnnotation";
view = [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:pinAnnotation];
if (view == nil) {
    view = [[OSAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation : annotation reuseIdentifier : pinAnnotation];
}
```

i have set delegate to self and able to call all delegate methods except didSelectAnnotationView.

Can anyone answer this please?

Thanks

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: have you set the map view's delegate?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog yes, i have set delegate and edited question

Comment: maybe the OSAnnotationView class has a protocol that you need your class to conform to in order to implement those delegate methods

Comment: it is bug in OSMapView

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at OSAnnotationView's documentation and saw that it has an *image* property. Try setting it to something non-nil and I think didSelectAnnotationView will work then. Also, try setting its *title* property to an empty string, if the setting the *image* property to non-nil doesn't work.

Comment: Kunal Shrivastava    thanks for the reply. I have tried setting image property as         view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""]; but does bot work for me and title property is not found.

Comment: In the demo project for OSMapView, I saw that they use OSPinAnnotationView in the viewForAnnotation while in your code you use OSAnnotationView. Could this be a problem? Can you try using OSPinAnnotationView instead?

Comment: Even use OSPinAnnotationView in viewForAnnotation doesn't work, delegate method is not calling.